# ios implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an objective c pointer to id is disallowed with arc

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting, compiler-errors, nsmutablearray

hi the following block of code is giving me error

```
-(void) addObserver: (id <ObserverDelegate>*) observer {    
     [self.queue addObject: observer]; //ERROR ON THIS LINE
}
```

error is saying 'implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an objective c pointer to id is disallowed with arc

my .h file

```
-(void) addObserver: (id <ObserverDelegate>*) observer;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray* queue;
```

Compile error on this line [self.queue addObject: observer];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using a pointer to an `id` for the `observer` parameter? Why not just have `id<ObserverDelegate>`?